# Whitespace in \includegraphics in combination with lualatex

Tags: graphics, luatex, includegraphics

When including a graphics file from a different directory than the current working directory having whitespace in its path, I usually put the path in double quotes like this:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

...

\includegraphics{"the/path/having whitespaces/file"}
```

Alternatively, I use the `\graphicspath` command:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{"the/path/having whitespaces/"}}

...

\includegraphics{file}
```

This works fine when using `pdflatex`. However, when using `lualatex` it produces an error claiming "cannot find image file".

Does anybody know how to include image files from paths with whitespaces in Lualatex?

Thanks so much.

Comment: you can try without the quotes but with the file extension: `\includegraphics{the/path/having whitespaces/file.pdf}`, lualatex will give a warning but probably include the image nevertheless. But it would be better to avoid spaces.

Comment: `\usepackage{grffile}`